# Comparing date with a date range in two tables

Tags: abap

I am trying to change another table using a table. I need to work with a table (we call it tab1) that uses a fixed date (workdate). The other table (tab2) uses a time range in two table entries (startdate and enddate).

I want to use tab1 to check if the entry in tab2 exists based on the dates. Then change the status of tab1 if it does not exist in tab2.

My idea was to use a LOOP AT outside of a READ TABLE, but im missing something important.

Regards Sruscht

EDIT: Sorry, that i wasnt clear with my question. Here is my code, which i tried once, but it set all status on delete.

```
LOOP AT lt_tab1 ASSIGNING <fs_tab1>
  WHERE workdate GE lt_tab2-enddate
  AND  workdate LE lt_tab2-startdate.

  ENDLOOP.

 IF sy-subrc NE 0.
"set lt_tab1-status on delete
  ENDIF.
```

If entries are deleted in table tab2, they are not changed in table tab1. In other words, tab1 is not updated.
The status in tab1 must then be changed so that the system is not displayed in other programs and/or applications.As already mentioned, tab1 uses a fixed date and tab2 uses a time range, which is described as start and end date.

My idea is to go through itab1 and look for the entry in itab2. If the entry is not in itab2, then the status of itab1 is changed.

Sorry that the question is so long, but I have big problems with this case.

The important thing I was talking about was the solution.

Comment: How relevant is performance in your case? I could imagine a rather simple solution, but it might get slow when tab2 gets too large. If that's a problem, then the solution gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: give table samples and the expected outcome. The idea is not clear

Comment: Sorry, im new on stackoverflow. i edited my text above. Maybe its more clear now. Sorry again for the long question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do that with two nested loops. One for all entries in lt_tab1 and an inner loop which scans lt_tab2 for any entries which match the current entry in tab1. You can then use a flag to indicate whether or not a matching entry was found.

```
DATA lv_found_match TYPE abap_bool.

LOOP AT lt_tab1 ASSIGNING <fs_tab1>.

   " find out if there is a matching entry in table 2 for this entry
   lv_found_match = abap_false.
   LOOP AT lt_itab2 ASSIGNING <fs_tab2>.
     IF <fs_tab2>-startdate <= <fs_tab1>-workdate AND
        <fs_tab2>-enddate >= <fs_tab1>-workdate.
       lv_found_match = abap_true.
       EXIT. " the LOOP AT
     ENDIF.
   ENDLOOP.

   IF lv_found_match = abap_true.
       " there is a match
   ELSE.
       " there isn't a match
   ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something like:

```
LOOP AT tab2
     WHERE startdate LE tab1-fixdate
       AND enddate GE tab1-fixdate
     ASSIGNING ...
...                                   "entry found
ENDLOOP.
IF sy-subrc NE 0.
  ...                                 "there was no corresponding entry
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a following question about the code: If it is not possible to use a sy-subrc within the loop, how to check if the entry exists

Comment: @Sankama you can check the sy-subrc after the LOOP, I modified the code accordingly.